# MVC Routes - Hide Index

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, html

I'm trying to omit the "/Index" from the Index actions in my application.  I know there's a million similar posts, but mine seems a little different.

Basically, I want to set my "home" controller/action to Time/Dashboard, but still have "Index" be the default action for every other controller.

When my default route was "Home" "Index".  The other pages were fine.  "Index" would hide.  But then I changed it to "Dashboard".  So now when I navigate to any controller/Index.  It needs the "/Index" otherwise I get 404.  Right now this is my routes:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Time", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: You need to change your action method name from `index` to `dashboard`..

Comment: Right. I guess if all of the "Index"s became "Dashboard"s the user would never know.  That seems kind of cheesy to me though.

But I see what you mean.  Why must I name Dashboard as "Dashboard"?  I should be able to call it "Index" because they will never see that either.

The issue is basically that non-authenticated users can go to http/myapplication and see MyController/Index.

And I wan't authenticated users to go to http/myapplication and see Time/Dashboard.  I guess I can just solve this with a redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this was a silly question.

The actual name of the "home" or default action doesn't really matter because no one will see it.

So I should either call that "Index" or call all of my other pages "Dashboard".

If I have a special case, then just use a RedirectToAction, or even return the other view if I really want to hide the url.